# Artifactory REST API: How to efficiently get permission targets for a user

Tags: rest, api, permissions, artifactory, target

I am trying to get the permission targets of an artifactory-user using artifactories REST API. I am currently using the [Get permission targets](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-GetPermissionTargets) call. This returns me all permissions targets which I then start filtering.
So my question is: Is there a REST API call for only getting the permission targets of a single user ?

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 3):

We are working on implementing such REST API. It will allow you getting permission target for a specific user / group. 
The API be available in one of the upcoming releases. You can watch for updates in [RTFACT-8567](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-8567).

Comment: Thank your very much for your quick answer. I didn't see that there is already a feature request.

Answer (score 1):

FYI - this functionality was added in Artifactory 6.9: 
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API+V2#ArtifactoryRESTAPIV2-GetPermissionTargetsPerUser
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API+V2#ArtifactoryRESTAPIV2-GetPermissionTargetsPerGroup